# How to stop PowerShell unrolling an array when called from another script

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have a script that is running in PowerShell 7 (for better Unicode support) and I need to run a certain batch of commands in PowerShell 5 due to some DLL incompatibility. This means (afaik) I can't use dot sourcing.

PowerShell 7 calling code:
`

```
$files = powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "$PSScriptRoot\FileInfo.ps1" -Path $FolderToProcess -Title $moduleTitle -GUID $guid
```

`FileInfo.ps1` loops through a set of files and returns an array of `PSCustomObject`

```
$arr = @()

foreach ($file in $finalFiles)  {

    $item = [PSCustomObject]@{
        i = $file.i
        j = $file.j
        k = $file.k
    }

    $arr += $item
}

return $arr
```

However, what happens when I try to use the `$files` variable in the calling script, is that the result of the called script is actually an array of strings and is useless.

How do I either:

A) Tell the calling script that the result of the script should be an array; **or**

B) Have the 'sending' script not process the result as a string and pass back an array as expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might [serialize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) the object (array) in the callee and deserialize it in the caller.

(As an aside: [try to avoid using the increase assignment operator (`+=`) to create a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/1701026))

**Callee** (`FileInfo.ps1`)

```
$arr = foreach ($file in $finalFiles)  {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        i = $file.i
        j = $file.j
        k = $file.k
    }
}
[System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Serialize($Arr)
```

**Caller** (PowerShell 7 calling code)

```
$PSSerial = powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "$PSScriptRoot\FileInfo.ps1" -Path $FolderToProcess -Title $moduleTitle -GUID $guid
$Files = [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Deserialize($PSSerial)
```